Estimating output voltage of an LC filter with unknown load using input voltage and load current
I am using a LC low-pass filter to smoothe the output of a switch-mode power supply.  I need to use a PLL to match the output voltage with a reference waveform, and would like to use feedback from a current sensor on the load to do so.
I attempted to solve this by finding the transfer function $H$ between $V_{out}$ and $V_{in}$, computing its value using a DFT, and finding the phase lag using the argument of the inner product $\langle H[k] \odot V_{in}[k],V_{target}[k] \rangle$ (where $H[k]$ denotes the kth frequency bin of the DFT of $h[t]$).
To derive the transfer function $H(j \omega) = \frac{V_{out}(j \omega)}{V_{in}(j \omega)}$, I used voltage and current division to find an expression for the load impedance:
$$
\begin{cases}
V_{out} \;=\; \displaystyle V_{in} \cdot \frac{Z_C \parallel Z_{\mathrm{load}}}{\,Z_C \parallel Z_{\mathrm{load}} + Z_L\,}, \\[6pt]
i_{\mathrm{load}} + i_C \;=\; \displaystyle \frac{V_{out}}{\,Z_C \parallel Z_{\mathrm{load}}\,}, \\[6pt]
i_{\mathrm{load}} \;=\; \displaystyle \frac{Z_C}{\,Z_C + Z_{\mathrm{load}}\,}\,\bigl(i_{\mathrm{load}} + i_C\bigr)
\end{cases} \Rightarrow Z_{load}
=Z_C \cdot \frac{V_{in} -I_{load} \cdot Z_L}{I_{load} \cdot (Z_C + Z_L)}.
$$
Then, I combined this with the voltage divider equation and substituted $Z_L = j \omega L$ and $Z_C = \frac{1}{j \omega C}$ to find that
$$
\frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}}
= Z_C \,\frac{V_{in} - i_L\,Z_L}{V_{in}\,\bigl(Z_C + Z_L\bigr)}
\quad\Rightarrow\quad
H(j\omega)
= \frac{V_C\bigl(j\omega\bigr)}{V_{in}\bigl(j\omega\bigr)}
= \frac{I_{load}\bigl(j\omega\bigr)\,j\omega L \;-\; V_{in}\bigl(j\omega\bigr)}
       {V_{in}\bigl(j\omega\bigr)\,\bigl(L\,C\,\omega^2 \;-\; 1\bigr)}.
$$
Mapping this into discrete time (under a DFT) by indexing frequency bins with $k$ and substituting $\omega = {\frac{2 \pi k}{nT}}$, we get
$$
H[k]
= \frac{I_{load}[k]j {\frac{2 \pi k}{nT}} L - V_{in}[k]}
       {V_{in}[k](LC\left(\frac{2 \pi k}{nT}\right)^2 - 1)} \\
= \frac{2 \pi j T n \frac{I_{load}[k]}{V_{in}[k]} L k - T^2 n^2}{4 \pi^{2} C L k^{2} - T^{2} n^{2}}.
$$
When I implemented this (relevant code in the estimate_transfer_function method) , my program predicted the incorrect value for $V_{out}$.

Welcome to our SE. It would help if you would a schematic and explain your assumptions around the different parts. Most power supplies and loads are not linear devices. so a simple linear model my not work here.
